# Insert group by from one measurment into another measurment

Tags: sql, influxdb

I have a measurement StoreSales with several tags. I want to do a Group By
only on the tags StoreNumber and Month and save this into another measurement.

This Group By on the measurement is the result I want inserted into another measurement:

```
SELECT SUM(value) 
FROM "DT"."2years"."StoreSales" 
WHERE StoreNumber !='' 
GROUP BY StoreNumber, Month
```

When I try this I get "ERR: mixing aggregate and non-aggregate queries is not supported":

```
SELECT Sum(value), StoreNumber, Month
INTO "DT"."2years"."StoreSalesByStorByMonth"
FROM "DT"."2years"."StoreSales"
WHERE StoreNumber !=''
GROUP BY StoreNumber, Month
```

Can anyone help with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the aggregating code in a subquery:

```
SELECT t.sumvalue, t.StoreNumber, t.Month 
INTO "DT"."2years"."StoreSalesByStorByMonth"
FROM (
  SELECT Sum(value) sumvalue, StoreNumber, Month
  FROM "DT"."2years"."StoreSales" 
  WHERE StoreNumber !='' 
  GROUP BY StoreNumber, Month
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try below. Since you can do the calculation part as your subquery and insert the final result into the table as needed.

```
SELECT * INTO "DT"."2years"."StoreSalesByStorByMonth"
FROM ( SELECT Sum(value) as sumvalue , StoreNumber, Month
FROM "DT"."2years"."StoreSales" WHERE StoreNumber !='' GROUP BY StoreNumber, Month) AS D
```

Comment: Thank you for both answers. For both those queries I get the error:
"ERR: error parsing query: found AS, expected ;"
If I replace "AS D" or "AS t" part with a ; I get the error 
ERR: mixing aggregate and non-aggregate queries is not supported

Comment: can you create a fiddle, with some of your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate your help!

I change the query a bit and this works:

```
SELECT * INTO "StoreSalesByStorByMonth" FROM 
( SELECT Sum(value) FROM "StoreSales" WHERE StoreNumber !='' GROUP BY StoreNumber, Month)
```

In the subquery I removed the other tags and only include Sum(value) and I also skipped the "AS D" or "AS T" part for the subquery.

Comment: I changed this now.